# What is the best login design for web applications?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, authentication

First, let's define "best" here. The "best" login design/flow/algorithm/technique for the purposes of this question should be:

- **Simple**. I don't think I need to explain why a simple system is better than a complicated one. OAuth 2, for example, is a very complicated system in my view. It defines, if I recall correctly, no less than nine different flows for granting an application access to a person's data. I find this superfluous, but that's not up for debate here.
- **Language-agnostic**. Please do not answer by giving an implementation. I don't want an implementation. I want a design (or several...). You *can* give examples, but the solution you propose should be easy to code in any (read: most) language without requiring significant workarounds for features that aren't there.
- **Secure**. The design should cover most common security problems on the net. XSS, CSRF, etc etc etc. I think a good set would be obtainable by going to [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) and searching for "security"...

Now for some smaller details:

- **JavaScript** is allowed. If a design can fall back to noscript environments, cool. But it's not a requirement.
- **Flash, Java applets** are not allowed. This goes against the language-agnostic clause above: if your design requires something that is only available through Flash or Java, it's a flaw.
- **Password storage**. There's a whole class of problems related to password storage. I don't want to hear about it.
- **Password transmission**. This *is* important. Transmitting a password in plain is just plain evil. Over SSL, it might be acceptable, but if you can have a system that is (relatively) secure without relying onto end-to-end encryption, it would be awesome.

Given all this, propose the "best" user/login/logout design/flow/algorithm/technique you think fits the conditions outlined above. Or tell me if you think it's a fool's errand! ;)

Comment: Simple and Secure are usually on two ends of the scale. Also, I think you're better of focusing on what's simple for the user than for the developer since that's more important. The easiest thing to do might be to get an oAuth library (e.g. from Janrain) and just implement that into your system.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have already given some thought to this question. Easiest way to look at the solution is to break it in to different layers.

**1) Database**

- Protected against sql injection. Just use prepared statements. Best and most secure!
- Always and I mean always, make sure the db user has only the access privileges it needs.

**2) Application**

- Use HTTPS. Don't even try to use anything else
- Don't store user-id in the cookie or anything. Use session's if you must
- If you don't have a session, generate a random id use that to look up a user. It's important to not have the cookie id not predictable.

**3) HTML/Javascript**

- Protect against CSRF by doing a token system. This is the only legit way
- Escape all you user input and sanitize it before writing to stream. In JSP, for example `<c:out/>` should be used
- Don't do anything secure in javascript. This is an obvious answer but sometimes it good to remind

**4) Etc**

- Keep patches up to date
- Don't recreate the wheel. In Rails, there are already some excellent authorization gems. Use them!

I think out all of these, using SSL is the most important. You can create the most complicated system to do a double submit with an awesome encyrption algorithm. But with all of that, at the end, you still won't have a system that is more secure and better tested than SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question.

I would consider:

1. **When required** I think web content should be public. So, as a user, I think it's best to have login only when it is required
2. **SSO** We should have mechanism to cross connect web applications more easily. I know that applications do not implement permissions the same way and we can't go wild there. That's where OAuth is filling the gap.
3. **Do not use CAPTCHA** (it is [considered inaccessible](http://www.w3.org/TR/turingtest/)).  Unless you use something similar, [like these](http://john.foliot.ca/not-the-blog-post-i-was-going-to-write-today/)
4. **csrf hidden field** to make sure that the form that are submitting is a valid one and not a  random post to an endpoint
5. **Always use SSL** the big guys is doing it and it's unsafe to let our users send their passwords in clear text. Some [proved](https://codebutler.com/2010/10/24/firesheep/) it.
6. **Always plan for without javascript**  Just in case, anyway it's not because we can do it that it's good to do.

That's my timeout for tonight. :)